# Sending ^C to Python subprocess objects on Windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have a test harness (written in Python) that needs to shut down the program under test (written in C) by sending it <kbd>^C</kbd>.  On Unix,

```
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

works perfectly.  On Windows, that throws an error ("signal 2 is not supported" or something like that).  I am using Python 2.7 for Windows, so I have the impression that I should be able to do instead

```
proc.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
```

but this doesn't do anything at all.  What do I have to do?  This is the code that creates the subprocess:

```
# Windows needs an extra argument passed to subprocess.Popen,
# but the constant isn't defined on Unix.
try: kwargs['creationflags'] = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
except AttributeError: pass
proc = subprocess.Popen(argv,
                        stdin=open(os.path.devnull, "r"),
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        **kwargs)
```

Comment: This might be the only way - http://code.activestate.com/recipes/347462-terminating-a-subprocess-on-windows/ with win32api oh or ctypes.

Comment: `subprocess.kill` will call `TerminateProcess` for me just fine, but that doesn't generate ^C.  I specifically need to fake the behavior of typing ^C at the console.

Comment: try this - http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/ . apparently SendKeys.SendKeys("^c") should do it.

Comment: That's not going to work; it communicates with the *active window*, which may not be the console window in which the process is running -- and if it does happen to be the active window, it would generate a ^C event for *every process* running in there, including the test harness itself.  The effect I want is that of [GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683155%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (and that is what `subprocess.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)` is _documented_ to do in Python 2.7...)

Answer (score 19):

There is a solution by using a wrapper (as described in the link Vinay provided) which is started in a new console window with the Windows *start* command.

Code of the wrapper:

```
#wrapper.py
import subprocess, time, signal, sys, os

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
  time.sleep(1)
  print 'Ctrl+C received in wrapper.py'

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print "wrapper.py started"
subprocess.Popen("python demo.py")
time.sleep(3) #Replace with your IPC code here, which waits on a fire CTRL-C request
os.kill(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)
```

Code of the program catching CTRL-C:

```
#demo.py

import signal, sys, time

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
  print 'Ctrl+C received in demo.py'
  time.sleep(1)
  sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print 'demo.py started'
#signal.pause() # does not work under Windows
while(True):
  time.sleep(1)
```

Launch the wrapper like e.g.:

```
PythonPrompt> import subprocess
PythonPrompt> subprocess.Popen("start python wrapper.py", shell=True)
```

You need to add some IPC code which allows you to control the wrapper firing the os.kill(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, 0) command. I used sockets for this purpose in my application.

**Explanation:**

Preinformation

- `send_signal(CTRL_C_EVENT)` does not work because `CTRL_C_EVENT` is only for `os.kill`. [[REF1]](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
- `os.kill(CTRL_C_EVENT)` sends the signal to all processes running in the current cmd window [[REF2]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- `Popen(..., creationflags=CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)` does not work because `CTRL_C_EVENT` is ignored for process groups. [[REF2]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
  This is a bug in the python documentation [[REF3]](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.send_signal)

Implemented solution

1. Let your program run in a different cmd window with the Windows shell command *start*.
2. Add a CTRL-C request wrapper between your control application and the application which should get the CTRL-C signal. The wrapper will run in the same cmd window as the application which should get the CTRL-C signal.
3. The wrapper will shutdown itself and the program which should get the CTRL-C signal by sending all processes in the cmd window the CTRL_C_EVENT.
4. The control program should be able to request the wrapper to send the CTRL-C signal. This might be implemnted trough IPC means, e.g. sockets.

Helpful posts were:

*I had to remove the http in front of the links because I'm a new user and are not allowed to post more than two links.*

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/dc9586ab-1ee8-41aa-a775-cf4828ac1239/#6589714f-12a7-447e-b214-27372f31ca11
- [Can I send a ctrl-C (SIGINT) to an application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows/2445728#2445728)
- [Sending SIGINT to a subprocess of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095549/sending-sigint-to-a-subprocess-of-python)
- http://bugs.python.org/issue9524
- http://ss64.com/nt/start.html
- http://objectmix.com/python/387639-sending-cntrl-c.html#post1443948

**Update: IPC based CTRL-C Wrapper**

Here you can find a selfwritten python module providing a CTRL-C wrapping including a socket based IPC.
The syntax is quite similiar to the subprocess module.

Usage:

```
>>> import winctrlc
>>> p1 = winctrlc.Popen("python demo.py")
>>> p2 = winctrlc.Popen("python demo.py")
>>> p3 = winctrlc.Popen("python demo.py")
>>> p2.send_ctrl_c()
>>> p1.send_ctrl_c()
>>> p3.send_ctrl_c()
```

Code

```
import socket
import subprocess
import time
import random
import signal, os, sys


class Popen:
  _port = random.randint(10000, 50000)
  _connection = ''

  def _start_ctrl_c_wrapper(self, cmd):
    cmd_str = "start \"\" python winctrlc.py "+"\""+cmd+"\""+" "+str(self._port)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd_str, shell=True)

  def _create_connection(self):
    self._connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self._connection.connect(('localhost', self._port))

  def send_ctrl_c(self):
    self._connection.send(Wrapper.TERMINATION_REQ)
    self._connection.close()

  def __init__(self, cmd):
    self._start_ctrl_c_wrapper(cmd)
    self._create_connection()


class Wrapper:
  TERMINATION_REQ = "Terminate with CTRL-C"

  def _create_connection(self, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('localhost', port))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    return conn

  def _wait_on_ctrl_c_request(self, conn):
    while True:
      data = conn.recv(1024)
      if data == self.TERMINATION_REQ:
        ctrl_c_received = True
        break
      else:
        ctrl_c_received = False
    return ctrl_c_received

  def _cleanup_and_fire_ctrl_c(self, conn):
    conn.close()
    os.kill(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)

  def _signal_handler(self, signal, frame):
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit(0)

  def __init__(self, cmd, port):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self._signal_handler)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    conn = self._create_connection(port)
    ctrl_c_req_received = self._wait_on_ctrl_c_request(conn)
    if ctrl_c_req_received:
      self._cleanup_and_fire_ctrl_c(conn)
    else:
      sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  command_string = sys.argv[1]
  port_no = int(sys.argv[2])
  Wrapper(command_string, port_no)
```

Comment: This technique (of the parent sending Ctrl+C to itself and its related processes) really works! I arrived at it independently, but I found that one should wait in the parent until SIGINT is handled, to avoid the signal interrupting e.g. system calls once it arrives.

Comment: the order of arguments is wrong. It should be `os.kill(pid, sig)` instead of `os.kill(sig, pid)`. Though `os.kill(0, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)`  doesn't interrupt `input()` call on Python 3.5 in vm with Windows 7 (the intent is to send Ctrl+C to all processes that share the console)

Comment: `send_signal(CTRL_C_EVENT)` works fine provided the child process is the leader of a process group and manually enables Ctrl+C via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE)`, which will be inherited by its own child processes. The documentation's claim that "`CTRL_C_EVENT` is ignored for process groups" is nonsense. Every process is in a process group. A new group initially has Ctrl+C disabled.

Comment: `os.kill(0, CTRL_C_EVENT)` or `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)` is ham handed. It sends the event to all processes attached to the console, including ancestors. Use a process group, and use Ctrl+Break if Ctrl+C is disabled. If it doesn't handle Ctrl+Break, then it likely also doesn't handle Ctrl+Close from closing the console window, since both events are mapped to C `SIGBREAK`. That's an oversight that should be submitted as a bug report if possible. All console applications that need special handling for a clean shutdown should handle Ctrl+Break and Ctrl+Close.

Answer (score 11):

### New answer:

When you create the process, use the flag `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`. And then you can send CTRL_BREAK to the child process. The default behavior is the same as CTRL_C, except that it won't affect the calling process.

---

### Old answer:

My solution also involves a wrapper script, but it does not need IPC, so it is far simpler to use.

The wrapper script first detaches itself from any existing console, then attach to the target console, then files the Ctrl-C event.

```py
import ctypes
import sys

kernel = ctypes.windll.kernel32

pid = int(sys.argv[1])
kernel.FreeConsole()
kernel.AttachConsole(pid)
kernel.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, 1)
kernel.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0, 0)
sys.exit(0)
```

The initial process must be launched in a separate console so that the Ctrl-C event will not leak. Example

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(['some_command'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

# Do something else

subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'ctrl_c.py', str(p.pid)]) # Send Ctrl-C
```

where I named the wrapper script as `ctrl_c.py`.

Comment: Very useful example! Thanks!
Instead of using ctrl_c.py as file, I wrote procedure and run it using multiprocessing.Process()  Work perfectly.

Comment: Important: the process to be killed has to have a console, so it should be started with `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, startupinfo=STARTUPINFO(dwFlags=STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW, wShowWindow=SW_HIDE)`

Answer (score 8):

Try calling the [`GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function using `ctypes`. As you are creating a new process group, the process group ID should be the same as the pid. So, something like

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.kernel32.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0, proc.pid) # 0 => Ctrl-C
```

should work.

**Update:** You're right, I missed that part of the detail. Here's [a post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/dc9586ab-1ee8-41aa-a775-cf4828ac1239/#6589714f-12a7-447e-b214-27372f31ca11) which suggests a possible solution, though it's a bit kludgy. More details are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows/2445728#2445728).

Comment: This didn't work either, so I reread the MSDN page and realized that it specifically says "you cannot send CTRL_C_EVENT to a process group, it has no effect".  Sending CTRL_BREAK_EVENT instead does work (without ctypes even), and does precisely what I want in a toy test program, but when I use it on my real program-under-test I get the "has encountered a problem and needs to close" dialog box over and over again.  Any ideas?

Comment: @zwol: the docs say *"This signal cannot be generated for process groups."* but `os.kill(0, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)` generates `KeyboardInterrupt` in `ipython` in Windows console for me as if I've pressed `Ctrl+C` manually i.e., you can use `CTRL_C_EVENT` with `0` (*"the signal is generated in all processes that share the console of the calling process."*).

Comment: MSDN is wrong that process groups can't receive Ctrl+C. It's a peculiar claim because every process is either the lead of a new process group or inherits the group of its parent. By default the first process in a new group has Ctrl+C disabled in its `ProcessParameters->ConsoleFlags`, which is inherited by child processes. The console itself is oblivious to this flag; it's handled within process by the control-thread startup function, `CtrlRoutine` in kernelbase.dll. A process that needs Ctrl+C support should override the inherited/initial flag value via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fully working example which **doesn't need any modification in the target script**.

This overrides the `sitecustomize` module so it might no be suitable for every scenario. However, in this case you could use a *.pth file in site-packages to execute code at the subprocess startup (see https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201001/running_code_at_python_startup.html).

**Edit** This works only out of the box for subprocesses in Python. Other processes have to manually call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE)`.

main.py

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import sys
import time


def main():
    env = os.environ.copy()
    env['PYTHONPATH'] = '%s%s%s' % ('custom-site', os.pathsep,
                                    env.get('PYTHONPATH', ''))
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        [sys.executable, 'sub.py'],
        env=env,
        creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
        )
    time.sleep(1)
    proc.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
    proc.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

custom-site\sitecustomize.py

```
import ctypes
import sys
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

if not kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, False):
    print('SetConsoleCtrlHandler Error: ', ctypes.get_last_error(),
          file=sys.stderr)
```

sub.py

```
import atexit
import time


def cleanup():
    print ('cleanup')

atexit.register(cleanup)


while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This isn't checking whether `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` failed. ctypes doesn't raise Python exceptions for a failed function call. That has to be done manually, or automated with a ctypes `errcheck` function. Anyway, we don't need to raise an exception in this case since there isn't anything to be done about it, but we should check for and log failure. Use `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)`. Then, for example, `if not kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, False): ` `print('SetConsoleCtrlHandler Error: ', ctypes.get_last_error(), file=sys.stderr)`.

Comment: That said, if we're in control of the child process, we should also have a C `SIGBREAK` handler for a clean shutdown. This will be invoked for both `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` and `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` (i.e. Ctrl+Break or closing the console window). Unfortunately the Python interpreter prevents handling a `SIGBREAK` that's generated from closing the console, since its C signal handler returns immediately and thus csrss.exe terminates the process before the Python handler executes. As a workaround, we can set a ctypes callback handler via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, which bypasses Python's C handler.

Answer (score 3):

I have a single file solution with the following advantages:
 - No external libraries. (Other than ctypes)
 - Doesn't require the process to be opened in a specific way.

The solution is adapted from [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15281070/2633114), but I think it's much more elegant in python.

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import sys
import time

# Terminates a Windows console app sending Ctrl-C
def terminateConsole(processId: int, timeout: int = None) -> bool:
    currentFilePath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    # Call the below code in a separate process. This is necessary due to the FreeConsole call.
    try:
        code = subprocess.call('{} {} {}'.format(sys.executable, currentFilePath, processId), timeout=timeout)
        if code == 0: return True
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        pass

    # Backup plan
    subprocess.call('taskkill /F /PID {}'.format(processId))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pid = int(sys.argv[1])

    import ctypes
    kernel = ctypes.windll.kernel32

    r = kernel.FreeConsole()
    if r == 0: exit(-1)
    r = kernel.AttachConsole(pid)
    if r == 0: exit(-1)
    r = kernel.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, True)
    if r == 0: exit(-1)
    r = kernel.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0, 0)
    if r == 0: exit(-1)
    r = kernel.FreeConsole()
    if r == 0: exit(-1)

    # use tasklist to wait while the process is still alive.
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        # We pass in stdin as PIPE because there currently is no Console, and stdin is currently invalid.
        searchOutput: bytes = subprocess.check_output('tasklist /FI "PID eq {}"'.format(pid), stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        if str(pid) not in searchOutput.decode(): break;

    # The following two commands are not needed since we're about to close this script.
    # You can leave them here if you want to do more console operations.
    r = kernel.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, False)
    if r == 0: exit(-1)
    r = kernel.AllocConsole()
    if r == 0: exit(-1)

    exit(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

For those interested in a "quick fix", I've made a [console-ctrl](https://pypi.org/project/console-ctrl) package based on [Siyuan Ren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60795888/10340019) to make it even easier to use.

Simply run `pip install console-ctrl`, and in your code:

```
import console_ctrl
import subprocess

# Start some command IN A SEPARATE CONSOLE
p = subprocess.Popen(['some_command'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
# ...

# Stop the target process
console_ctrl.send_ctrl_c(p.pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have been trying this but for some reason ctrl+break works, and ctrl+c does not. So using `os.kill(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)` fails, but doing `os.kill(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, 1)` works. I am told this has something to do with the create process owner being the only one that can pass a ctrl c? Does that make sense?

To clarify, while running fio manually in a command window it appears to be running as expected. Using the CTRL + BREAK breaks without storing the log as expected and CTRL + C finishes writing to the file also as expected. The problem appears to be in the signal for the CTRL_C_EVENT.

It almost appears to be a bug in Python but may rather be a bug in Windows. Also one other thing, I had a cygwin version running and sending the ctrl+c in python there worked as well, but then again we aren't really running native windows there.

example:

```
import subprocess, time, signal, sys, os
command = '"C:\\Program Files\\fio\\fio.exe" --rw=randrw --bs=1M --numjobs=8 --iodepth=64 --direct=1 ' \
    '--sync=0 --ioengine=windowsaio --name=test --loops=10000 ' \
    '--size=99901800 --rwmixwrite=100 --do_verify=0 --filename=I\\:\\test ' \
    '--thread --output=C:\\output.txt'
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
  time.sleep(1)
  print 'Ctrl+C received in wrapper.py'

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print 'command Starting'
subprocess.Popen(command)
print 'command started'
time.sleep(15) 
print 'Timeout Completed'
os.kill(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

(This was supposed to be a comment under [Siyuan Ren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60795888/13095983) but I don't have enough rep so here's a slightly longer version.)

If you don't want to create any helper scripts you can use:

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(['some_command'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

# Do something else

subprocess.run([
    sys.executable,
    "-c",
    "import ctypes, sys;"
    "kernel = ctypes.windll.kernel32;"
    "pid = int(sys.argv[1]);"
    "kernel.FreeConsole();"
    "kernel.AttachConsole(pid);"
    "kernel.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, 1);"
    "kernel.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0, 0);"
    "sys.exit(0)",
    str(p.pid)
]) # Send Ctrl-C
```

But it won't work if you use PyInstaller - `sys.executable` points to your executable, not the Python interpreter. To solve that issue I've created a tiny utility for Windows: https://github.com/anadius/ctrlc

Now you can send the Ctrl+C event with:

```py
subprocess.run(["ctrlc", str(p.pid)])
```