# Gently kill a process created with Python's subprocess.Popen() in Windows

Tags: python, subprocess, kill-process

I'm trying to run a python script that runs, with subprocess.popen (), one or more instances of another python script. At some point I need to finish them gently. These scripts execute a while loop and when ctrl-c is catched they execute a clean-up routine and terminate.

At the beginnig my idea was to send ctrl-c to those scripts with subproc.send_signal() but it doesn't work.
I tryed to use subproc.terminate() or os.kill(os.kill(subproc.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)) and other solution founded on Internet but nothing works well.

How can I gently terminate my scripts? Is the way I run my scripts right?
Here is my code:

```
processes = []
    for i in range(0, capsules_number):
        p = subprocess.Popen(["python.exe ", "Capsula.py ", str(i)])
        processes.append(p)

    input("Press any key to terminate programs")

    for p in processes:
        # Terminate process
        processes.remove(p)
```

Comment: ctrl+c sends a `signal.SIGINT` signal to the process, so did you think about sending those ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending ^C to Python subprocess objects on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085604/sending-c-to-python-subprocess-objects-on-windows)

Comment: Yes I already tried all your suggestions but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

From the `subprocess` documentation:

> CTRL_C_EVENT and CTRL_BREAK_EVENT can be sent to processes started with a `creationflags` parameter which includes CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP.

Comment: Thanks! can you tell me something more? I don't know what process group are...

Comment: This answer [doesn't actually work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Read the duplicate.